# tikzpicture won't compile

Tags: tikz-pgf

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{rect} = [draw, rectangle, fill=white!20,text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{elli} = [draw, ellipse, fill=white!20, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{circ} = [draw, circle, fill=white!20,minimum width=8pt, inner sep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{diam} = [draw, diamond, fill=white!20,text width=6em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{rect} = [draw, rectangle, fill=white!20,text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm,auto]
\node[rect,rounded corners] (stepl) {start};
\node[rect, below of=step1] (step2) {car};
\node[diam, below of=step2, node distance=2.5cm] (step3) {obd-ii, gps, tpms};
\node[rect, left of=step3, node distance=3.5cm] (step4) {no};
\node[rect, rounded corners, below of=step3, node distance=3cm](step5){end};
\path[line] (step1) -- (step2);
\path[line] (step2) -- (step3);
\path[line] (step3) -- node [above,near start] {no} (step4);
\path[line] (step3) -- node [left,near start] {yes} (step5);
\path[line,rounded corners] (step4) -(step1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{chart.}
\label{f1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "What's wrong" is that your example is far too long.  Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497.  Also, please add some text explaining your problem, not just an uninformative title and code dump.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of what you are trying to draw?

Comment: It gives the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.4 \usetikzlibrary` as you are using tikz commands without loading the `tikz` package.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few mistakes (or at least recommended changes) in your code.

- load the package `tikz`, not `graphicx`
- use libraries `shapes` and `arrows.meta`
- use `\tikzset` as shown below, not `\tikzstyle`
- `latex` instead of `latex'`
- `(step4) -(step1)` should be `(step4) |- (step1)`
- `(stepl)` should be `(step1)`
- Place `\usetikzlibrary` before `\begin{document}`

Complete code is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    rect/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white!20,text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=2em},
    elli/.style={draw, ellipse, fill=white!20, minimum height=2em},
    circ/.style={draw, circle, fill=white!20,minimum width=8pt, inner sep=10pt},
    diam/.style={draw, diamond, fill=white!20,text width=6em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt},
    rect/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white!20,text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=2em},
    line/.style={draw, -latex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm,auto]
\node[rect,rounded corners] (step1) {start};
\node[rect, below of=step1] (step2) {car};
\node[diam, below of=step2, node distance=2.5cm] (step3) {obd-ii, gps, tpms};
\node[rect, left of=step3, node distance=3.5cm] (step4) {no};
\node[rect, rounded corners, below of=step3, node distance=3cm](step5){end};
\path[line] (step1) -- (step2);
\path[line] (step2) -- (step3);
\path[line] (step3) -- node [above,near start] {no} (step4);
\path[line] (step3) -- node [left,near start] {yes} (step5);
\path[line,rounded corners] (step4) |- (step1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{chart.}
\label{f1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- In your MWE contain errors and in it is easy going to lost ...
- needed correction are clearly listed in nice @Sandy G answer (+1)
- here are some pff-topic suggestions, which, after considering them, make your flowchart code more concise and clear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,      % new
                positioning,
                quotes,      % new
                shapes.geometric}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
    start chain = A going below,
     arr/.style = {-{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, semithick,
                   rounded corners},
     box/.style = {draw,
                   minimum width=6em, minimum height=8mm,
                   align=center, on chain, join=by arr},
decision/.style = {box, diamond, aspect=1.2, inner xsep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\small},
%
suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}
        }
\makeatother
%
\node [box,
       rounded corners] (s1) {start};
\node [box]             (s2) {car};
\node [decision]        (s3) {obd-ii, gps,\\ tpms};
\node [box,
       rounded corners] (s5)    {end};
%
\node [box, suspend join,
       left=of s3 ] (s4) {no};
%
\draw[arr]  (s3) edge ["No"]    (s4)
            (s4) |- (s1);
\path       (s3)  to  ["Yes"]   (s5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flowchart, renewed :-)}
\label{fig:f1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE are changed names of nodes styles as well their names that will not interfere with yours. The compilation result of the proposed solution is:

[image]